# Getting PowerA Wired Gamecube Controller working in PC?

Tags: drivers, compatibility, device-manager, game-controller, emulation

So I recently bought a [PowerA Wired Gamecube Controller](https://store.powera.com/Product/1507847-Wired_Controller_for_Nintendo_Switch-GameCube_Style_Purple) for my Nintendo Switch. It works flawlessly in that console, but recently I have become interested in PC Emulation and I have thought about playing Gamecube games in the Dolphin Emulator with this controller.

When I go into the documentation for Dolphin, they only mention they have [support for the WiiU Gamecube adapter](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=How_to_use_the_Official_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_for_Wii_U_in_Dolphin). There is no mention of Gamecube controllers that don't need this adapter (mine just uses a standard USB2.0 to connect).

The logical solution to this would be to use a software that takes the inputs from this controller and creates, say, a virtual Xbox controller, and maps my inputs to inputs in that virtual controller. A good example of this would be [TocaEdit's Xbox 360 COntroller Emulator](https://www.x360ce.com/).

The problem is that my controller is not recognized as a Game Controller. It shows up in the Device Manager like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PnhE.jpg). If I use Zadig and install standard the WinUSB driver on it, it shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFhf.jpg), but it still [isn't recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUZOZ.jpg) by either Dolphin or the Xbox Controller Emulator.

My question is: Is there anything else that I can try to set it up? This controller is not very popular so there aren't a lot of resources online about it. I'm also not sure I can even use it on my PC. Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I've gotten my PowerA wired Gamecube controller to work in every game I've tried using XOutput. Highly recommended! It seems the controller comes with some Dinput support, but with XOutput I'm covered for every situation. Hope this helps!

Comment: Explaining HOW you use this tool to make this work will make this an answer. Right now it is just a comment, and should not be posted as an answer.